# Find the Limit (n to infinity)

Tags: limits, infinity

Hi I have a question regarding of limits to infinity please help! Thank You!

The question states the user to find the following limit:

$  \lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 ({\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n+1]{x}}) $

Where $(x > 0) $

Thank You!!!

Comment: The limit is equivalent to $\lim_{m \to 0} \frac{x^{1/m} - x^{m/m+1}}{m^2}$. Use L'Hospital's rule twice to get the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite it as
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2+n)\left(x^{1/(n^2+n)}-1\right)\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}x^{1/(n+1)}\right)
$$
and use the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(x^{1/n}-1\right)=\log(x)
$$
which is the inverse of
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=e^x
$$

Answer (score 2):

Using Taylor series:
$$n^2({\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n+1]{x}})=n^2\left(\exp\left(\frac1n\log x\right)-\exp\left(\frac1{n+1}\log x\right)\right)\sim_\infty n^2\log x\left(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1}\right)\sim_\infty \log x$$

Comment: so would the final answer be 0 or infinity?

Comment: No the limit of your sequence is $\log x$.