# How to solve the following limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2\cdot(\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n+1]{x})$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2\cdot(\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n+1]{x})$$

My first idea, since it's $0 \cdot \infty$ (might be wrong though) was to re-write the multiplication as a fraction $\frac{\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n+1]{x}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$ and apply L'Hospital but I don't think it gives the right answer (wolfram says it's ln x) so I'm pretty much out of ideas since I don't see any remarkable limit there

Thanks in advance.

By the way, I found the problem in a book that's for eleventh grade (or junior year) so I'm pretty sure there's a trick somewhere that I'm not aware of

Comment: You applied L'Hospital with respect to what, $n$?

Comment: L'Hospital works, show us what you tried.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Formally it is not correct, but if you think in $n$ as a real variable, the function is continuous.

Comment: @ajotatxe  I am wondering where the mistake is in the application of L'Hospital. Hopefully OP will show what he tried.

Comment: Related [Find the limit $\lim_\limits{n\to{\infty}}n^2(\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[{n + 1}]{x})$ and my inquiry about Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165649/find-the-limit-lim-limitsn-to-inftyn2-sqrtnx-sqrtn-1x-an). Also see [Find the Limit (n to infinity)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708348/find-the-limit-n-to-infinity)

Comment: @Sil, it's not just related, it looks like a proper dupe. Any reasons for not raising as a duplicate?

Comment: @rtybase The first one actually asks about Cesaro-Stoltz application, the second one looks like a dupe but the quality seems to be bad. But feel free to mark it that way...

Comment: @Sil, no, no ... the privilege is yours. I will support the vote though.

Comment: @rtybase I've retracted it already, so I cannot anymore on this one. It's okay, it''s not like we get any reputation for marking duplicates...

Comment: @Sil you never know, all these things add up, I can tell. Besides, it's our (as part of the community) duty to keep it clean and help others (in this case: promote old questions, help new joiners to look for answers before asking).